# DataGridView Header Stacked - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, header, c#-to-vb.net

I need the columns Headers to be Stacked, like Header Cells Merged. The Same as in this image.

[image]

Please Refer to this link. It is done with C#. It does exactly what I need.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474418/DataGridViewplus-e2-80-93plusStackedplusHeader

But the Problem is, Im working on vbproj and It cant include this C#.
I used some code converters and ended with some errors in raising events, etc.

Is there any way to get this in VB.NET

Or Is there any other way to make this stacked Headers??

Comment: Try Convert C# code to VB.NET, there are many Online converters are there.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question about conversion, but the easiest solution is to keep the code in C# as a separate project, then add it as a project reference in your VB.NET project.