# C# How to design winforms DataGridView Header as below picture

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, windows-forms-designer, datagridviewcolumn

[image: please check the picture]

combine the first three column to one and text animal, then also text "dog" "cat" "bird" in the three columns below the "animal " column, I want to know how to combine and design the header in datagridview like that.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928893/datagridview-header-stacked-vb-net

Comment: No built in functionality for that purpose. You need to write code

Comment: The question is similar, but it doesn't havbe any useful answer. You will need to owner-draw the headers in the cell-painting event!

Comment: so my question will be How to draw the header like that

Comment: Indeed. First make room, then decide how you want to store the necessary string and placement data, mabye in the Clumns' Tags, finally code the CellPainting event. When you have tried something, post it and we'll check it out..